# Using http.GetFile how to prevent bad url requests from creating new files

Tags: nativescript

I am using the `http.getFile` function to download files from an api. I am having a issue where files are still created, even though the url passed to `getFile` is invalid or returning errors. After some research it appears the `getFile` will always create a new file, is there a way to prevent `getFile` from creating a new file if the url is invalid?

The only work around I can think is to check the file size after calling the `getFile` and deleting it if there is no data?

In the example below I was tying to use the `File.exists`, but it always returns `true`.

```
return http.getFile(fullUrl, filePath)
.then(function(r){

    // Test - Check if file Exists
    console.log("Check File Exist: " + fs.File.exists(filePath));
}, function(error) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the "fullUrl" is a valid url before requesting:

```
var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
var isUrlValid = regexp.test(fullUrl);
if(isUrlValid){
http.getFile(fullUrl, filePath)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify some more, the url is actually formatted correctly. I am trying to catch cases where the url might return an error response. Like if the session is expired, or maybe the file requested does not exist on server.